# Remove the second last character of a string

Tags: javascript

How would I remove the second last character of a string using pure javascript. I can make it more specific by saying the last character of the string is ','. But there are other ',' present in the string. I just want the 2nd last one to be gone

here is the string

```
var data = [{
  "Store_ID": "46305",
  "inv list id": "jonesny-46305-inventory",
  "Store Address": "739 Reading Avenue Suite #306",
  "zip": "19610"
}, {
  "Store_ID": "48760",
  "inv list id": "jonesny-46305-inventory",
  "Store Address": "1665 State Hill Rd",
  "zip": "19610"
}, {
  "Store_ID": "48811",
  "inv list id": "jonesny-46305-inventory",
  "Store Address": "1665 State Hill Road",
  "zip": "19601"
}, {
  "Store_ID": "53046",
  "inv list id": "jonesny-46305-inventory",
  "Store Address": "2630 Westview Dr",
  "zip": "19610"
}, ]
```

Notice the last ','

the script which is producing it is this

```
var newVar = '[';

for(var x in pdict.Stores){
    newVar += '{' + '"Store_ID":"' + x.ID + '",';
    newVar += '"inv list id":"' + x.inventoryList.ID + '",';
    newVar += '"Store Address":"' + x.address1 + '",';
    newVar += '"zip":"' + x.postalCode + '"},';
}

newVar += ']';
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried, the source string, and the desired outcome?

Comment: [{"Store_ID":"46305","inv list id":"jonesny-46305-inventory","Store Address":"739 Reading Avenue Suite #306","zip":"19610"},{"Store_ID":"48760","inv list id":"jonesny-46305-inventory","Store Address":"1665 State Hill Rd","zip":"19610"},{"Store_ID":"48811","inv list id":"jonesny-46305-inventory","Store Address":"1665 State Hill Road","zip":"19601"},{"Store_ID":"53046","inv list id":"jonesny-46305-inventory","Store Address":"2630 Westview Dr","zip":"19610"},]

Notice the last ','

Comment: Please edit the question with your changes.

Comment: That's not a string.  (That's a space station!)

Comment: I'm assuming this was generated by a server side language (perhaps PHP?). If so, you should have told it on the last loop to not put a comma. Chrome will actually ignore that last comma anyway, but I don't know how other browsers would handle it.

Comment: since you mentioned server side..yes it is a server side javascript...

I am adding it in the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will truncate the last two characters of the string (and add a `]` back on):

```
str = str.substring(0, str.length - 2)+ ']';
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/D9qm6/)**

Comment: It's an array of objects, not a string.